# Different gmail account for different websites

Tags: firefox, youtube, gmail, archlinux

Is there any methods to use different gmail account for different website. It means I would like to use `subash@gmail.com for youtube`, `subash2@gmail.com for google classroom as default`.

I donot want to logout and again sign it to the account.Also I dont want to open multiple browser. Currently I am running arc linux with mozilla firefox as default browser.I tried google search but no help.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a New Private Window for one thing and a normal window for the other.